# Custom icon display setting during jstree node addition

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am trying to add different icons for different types of nodes (I have different meaning for each nodes). I have designed all the icons for different types of node and am looking to plug those in during creation of node. This is how I am adding nodes to jstree :

```
$("#tree").jstree("create",$(id), "inside",  { "data" : str, "state" : "leaf", "attr" : { "id" : "child"+no, "value" : str2} }, null, true);
```

How should I modify this line of code to specify my own icon during creation of node? Any pointers would also be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use the "types" plugin you can define your own icon there.
Take a look here http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types And if you want to use more icons, define a type for each icon you want to use. I hope this helps.